# Workaround for output=graph with bazel cquery

Tags: graph, build, bazel

I'm trying to obtain a dependency graph (either as an image or in text-form) from a `bazel cquery`. According to the documentation, the option `--output=graph` is currently only supported by `bazel query`, but not by `cquery`. Unfortunately, in our project it's not possible to use `query` since it fetches some external dependencies with restricted access. Only using a config (with `cquery`) prevents fetching these restricted dependencies.

Is there a work-around to somehow get a graph-like structure from `cquery`? The default output is just a flattened list which seems to contain no information on the inter-dependencies between the targets.

If the inter-dependencies can somehow be printed, I guess it would be quite easy to reconstruct an image from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works: Using `query` instead of `cquery` and appending the flag `--keep_going` to ignore errors caused by external dependencies that cannot be fetched by everybody. Then `--output=graph` can be used.

**Note:** The result might be different from a configured `cquery`, but for our purposes, it doesn't matter much.